# How know if the combobox was binding?

Tags: c#, winforms

My code is:

```
private void cmbMaritalStatus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cmbMaritalStatus.BindingContext==null)
    {
        cmbMaritalStatus.Text = string.Empty;
        FillComboboxes();
    }
}
public void FillComboboxes()
{
    cmbMaritalStatus.SetBindingToLookup(dataSource);
    cmbMaritalStatus.BindSelected(bscAssistanceFileModel, pnr.Get(x => x.AssistanceFile.MaritalStatus));
}
```

the object `dataSource` is type of `IEnumerable<CDX_MaritalStatus>`

and I want that if this Combobox not was Binding so I send it to function
that bind it.
I try this code but in the first time it's looks good
But when that I debug it and I see that it's full, it's enter to the if
although that it's was Binding

The solution is only flag??

Comment: Show us how you bind the data to the combobox in `FillComboboxes()`

Comment: It seems you looking for `if(comboBox1.DataSource == null)` to check if `ComboBox` doesn't have any data source.

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know how you bind the data to the combobox. But you can try to check if the DataSource is null - like this:

```
DataSource source = cmbMaritalStatus.DataSource;
if (source.Count == 0)
{
    cmbMaritalStatus.Text = string.Empty;
    FillComboboxes();
}
```

Comment: I'm try it but it not tell ne if it's was bound or not.

Comment: then add the code of your `FillComboboxes` function to the question, so I can see how you fill the comboboxes...

Comment: `public void FillComboboxes()
        {
            cmbMaritalStatus.SetBindingToLookup(dataSource);
            cmbMaritalStatus.BindSelected(bscAssistanceFileModel, pnr.Get(x => x.AssistanceFile.MaritalStatus));

        }' the `dataSource` is type of `IEnumerable<CDX_MaritalStatus>`

Comment: I'm writing the function `FillComboboxes` look at my edit